# Transpile type predicates in typescript

Tags: typescript

This is a question I have from reading the typescript playground examples. Here we have two type predicate functions. The process of tranpilation in javascript erases the `is` statements, which checks types. I assume the code that eventually runs is the transpiled js code. So how does typescript check types if the `is` statements are no longer there?

```
function isAnInternetOrder(order: PossibleOrders): order is InternetOrder {
  return order && "email" in order;
}

function isATelephoneOrder(order: PossibleOrders): order is TelephoneOrder {
  return order && "callerNumber" in order;
}
```

Transpiled js:

```
function isAnInternetOrder(order) {
    return order && "email" in order;
}
function isATelephoneOrder(order) {
    return order && "callerNumber" in order;
}
```

Comment: Typescript "runs" in your IDE and at compile time. It prevents the code from compiling when something is off with the types. At runtime it's just plain Javascript with no clue of the types whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about transpiling, typescript doesn't look at the transpiled js output. So to answer your question, your .ts files (i.e. .tsx) is what IDE would be type checking and the original typescript files stay intact.